# Given a 2d list in python, how to append only certain values to a new list?

Tags: python, list

So let's say I have a list:

```
lst = [[5,1,2,3],[2,3,4,5,7],[1,10,9,8,7]]
```

And I have another list which contains the indices of the elements I want to delete from the previous list:

```
indexes_to_del = [[0,2],[1,2],[1,3],[2,2]]
```

So that we get the following list:

```
new_lst = [[5,1,3],[2,3,7],[1,10,8,7]]
```

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

My initial feeling is using del would not be the most efficient way, and I have to find some way to create a new list and append the desired values to it.

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you already know what to do but just haven't tried it yet. I would recommend just implementing it using `del` as you already suggest and seeing if that's fast enough for your use-case. It's no use optimizing if you hardly spend any time doing it anyway ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one possible way to achieve this using a nested list comprehension:

```
new_lst = [[e for j, e in enumerate(lst[i]) if [i, j] not in indexes_to_del] for i in range(len(lst))]
```

Output:

```
[[5, 1, 3], [2, 3, 7], [1, 10, 8, 7]]
```

Comment: To make it little efficient make `indexes_to_del` a set.

Comment: @Ch3steR I'm not 100% certain what you're saying?

Comment: `indexes_to_del` is a list and membership test in lists is `O(n)` but in sets it's `O(1)`. It wouldn't even matter for such small lists.

Comment: @Ch3steR gotcha. In that case though you'd have to change it to a set of tuples since you can't hash lists. As you say, probably not much difference for lists of this size.